# Edge Injects Doubleclick iframe into Website Pages

Tags: microsoft-edge, code-injection, inject, double-click

I just got a new Windows 11 computer after retiring Windows 7 and never used Edge until now.

In Microsoft's Edge's F12 Developer Window, I noticed that Edge is injecting a doubleclick iframe at the end of the pages just before the end of the body tag.

I do not see it with CTRL-u.

Firefox does not have it. I haven't looked at Chrome.

```
<iframe src="https://bid.g.doubleclick.net/xbbe/pixel?d=KAE" style="display: none;"></iframe>
```

What is that about and is it really on my live webpages?

If so, do you have a code to stop it?

Or, does this happen after the page loads and I cannot stop it except by suing MS for adding to my pages? If the latter, perhaps a class-action lawsuit is in order.

Comment: Is this issue only on a specific site? Can you share the site URL so we can reproduce the issue? Also, you can see if the same issue exists in Chrome.

Comment: Odd, I saw it and don't see it now. That makes me think that it's either a random event or it was there once and MS/doubleclick already has my info.  It WAS there because I copy-n-pasted it from developers' tools. If I do see it again, I'll definitely be back. If anyone can decipher the link, that'd help.